# RegExp search for special character "["

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having difficulty scanning for the special character "[". After looking around, I've tried:

```
var regEx = new RegExp(someValue + "[\x5B]");  // "5B" is the hex-value for "["
```

(I DO want case-sensitivity and I ONLY want the first occurrence so I intentionally didn't add any modifiers.)

I have been looking and looking, and I still have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If this is a bone-headed question, I'm sorry, but I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm still learning all the ins and outs.

Comment: It works for me: `RegExp("[\x5B]").test("[")` yields true.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick answers, I truly appreciate it. However, to whom ever cast the down vote, thanks for having patience with a newbie; I'm only trying to learn.

Comment: Regexes are _fun!_ But I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. For starters, you need to learn which characters are special: "metacharacters" that need to be escaped (and the rules are different inside and outside character classes.) There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Comment: I've saved it in my bookmarks! Thanks for the advice, I bumped up your comment. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regEx = new RegExp(someValue + "\\[");
```

You simply have to escape it with a backslash. The backslash is double because it is a javascript special character as well.

Comment: You're right, this is perfect! I was trying to use RegExp.lastIndex(), which does not work without the "g" modifier. It was, in essence, turned off, and I was trying to use it to tell me if my search had a result. Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(str));
```

See: [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486)

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine, if you just escape the character:

```
new RegExp(someValue + "\\[");
```

You need two backslashes because the backslash is the escape character for strings too. So `\\[` will result in the string `\[` which is what we need.

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect explanation. I selected the other answer because it popped up first, but I gave you an up vote for the amazing help! Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Both the regex `.\[` and `.[\x5B]` match the sub-string `"e["` from the text:

```
"some[text"
```

as you can see yourself:

---

http://ideone.com/iR78l

```
var text = "some[text";
print(text.match(/.\[/));
```

---

and http://ideone.com/qvsCz

```
var text = "some[text";
print(text.match(/.[\x5B]/));
```

Answer (score -2):

I think all you need is /[/ for your expression to find the first occurrence of "["

If there's something more complicated you're looking for, check out this tool:
http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

It's a life-saver for creating regular expressions.

Comment: My JavaScript console refuses `/[/` as an invalid regular expression.